# SVG, overflow (scrolling) does not seem to work on mobile, tab

Tags: html, svg

I have the following tags used on a HTML (SVG) solution I am writing,

```
<div class="divSVG" id="divSVG">
<svg id="mySVG" width="1600" height="1200" overflow="scroll"></svg> 
</div>
```

And it shows up with nicely on a PC (Chrome, IE, Netscape etc.) with scrollbars - because my drawing goes beyond the borders of the browser (divSVG width = 100%). But trying the same on my mobile and Nexus tab (both using Chrome, Androide 4.2) the scrollbars does not show up and I have no way of scrolling vertically or horizontally to see the drawings extremeties.

Any thoughts on what could be the problem - thought Chrome would work the same accross devices? Thanks in advance for providing support.